# Import error with PyQt5 : undefined symbol:_ZNSt12out_of_rangeC1EPKc,versionQt_5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I had watched a video on YouTube about making your own web browser using PyQt5. Link to video: https://youtu.be/z-5bZ8EoKu4,
I found it interesting and decided to try it out on my system. Please note that I am using a derivative of Arch Linux (Garuda).
Here's the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://google.com'))
        self.setCentrealWidget()
        self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Chrome Killer')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Unfortunately, I encountered an error with imports. I tried reading the documentation and surfed forums but returned empty-handed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tanishq/Tanishq/VS Code/Own Browser/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ImportError: /home/tanishq/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZNSt12out_of_rangeC1EPKc, version Qt_5
```

Other relevant details:

- Python version: 3.9.6
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.2

Comment: try update pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine: `python -m pip install pyqt5 --upgrade`

Comment: TYPO: change `self.setCentrealWidget()` to `self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)`

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for picking the errors out, I got the code rectified and updated pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine but it still shows the same error.

Comment: How did you install pyqtwebengine initially? Did you use pacman?

Comment: @Daredevil3722 You should use the official pyqt and pyqtwebengine packages provided by your distro. Don't mix and match modules from pip, otherwise you risk running into compatibility issues. If you still get that error with the official packages, you should report it on your distro's issue-tracker as a bug.

Comment: @eyllanesc I had installed pyqtwebengine using pip, command : pip install PyQtWebEngine

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh I see, I get that....I'll try uninstalling from pip and installing through pacman. Thank you for the info !

Comment: I got the code working now, it opens a fullscreen window with the application name 'Chrome Killer' and has google's home page, but I get this in my terminal everytime I run the code :
```
Icon theme "adwaita" not found.
 Icon theme "ubuntu-mono" not found.
 Icon theme "yaru" not found.
 Icon theme "Mint-X" not found.
 Icon theme "elementary" not found.
```
 Any idea on how to rectify these?

Comment: @Daredevil3722 You can usually deal with those kind of issues by doing a web-search on the error/warning message. In this case, it seems to be garuda-specific problem - see here: https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/missing-system-icon/7834. (PS: please don't use answers to ask follow-up questions).

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for your help.
And yea, sorry for that, I am new in posting questions here and I am not used to it, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4):

I got the code working...I had just run two commands

firstly:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyqt5
```

and the last command:

```
sudo pacman -S pyqt5
```

thank you @eyllanesc and @ekhumoro for your help

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt install python3-qtpy`

fixed it for me

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.