# Spyder (pip installed) doesn't start anymore with the error: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version QT_5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, spyder

On Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-43-generic) I freshly updated [spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) using `pip` as follow:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade spyder
```

everything went fine, but it throws this error when I start spyder now:

```
$ spyder 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 248, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 57, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 29, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5
```

Some more info:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.4
```

```
$ pip list | grep -i pyqt
PyQt5                         5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.11.0
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.5
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
```

```
$ pip list | grep -i spyder
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
spyder                        5.3.2
spyder-kernels                2.3.2
```

And I'm not able to uninstall PyQt5:

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall pyqt5
Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.15.6
ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQt5 5.15.6, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build.
```

The last line being printed in red in the terminal.

From that point, I'm not able to find relevant information on how to debug this in order to make spyder work again.

What could I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --force-reinstall spyder
```

it will probably throw some errors such as:

```
  Attempting uninstall: PyQtWebEngine
    Found existing installation: PyQtWebEngine 5.15.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQtWebEngine 5.15.5, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build.
```

which, if you try to update it individually will show:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install -U PyQtWebEngine
Requirement already satisfied: PyQtWebEngine in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.15.5)
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine-5.15.6-cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (230 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5>=5.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.7)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQtWebEngine-Qt5>=5.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (12.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQt5>=5.15.4->PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.2)
Installing collected packages: PyQtWebEngine
  Attempting uninstall: PyQtWebEngine
    Found existing installation: PyQtWebEngine 5.15.5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQtWebEngine 5.15.5, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build.
```

Therefore, in that case, run the installation using the `--ignore-installed` flag on the incriminated package, which *should* install it without any trouble:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --ignore-installed PyQtWebEngine
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine-5.15.6-cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (230 kB)
Collecting PyQtWebEngine-Qt5>=5.15.0
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (67.5 MB)
Collecting PyQt5>=5.15.4
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (8.4 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (359 kB)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (59.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyQtWebEngine-Qt5, PyQt5-Qt5, PyQt5-sip, PyQt5, PyQtWebEngine
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.15.7 PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2 PyQt5-sip-12.11.0 PyQtWebEngine-5.15.6 PyQtWebEngine-Qt5-5.15.2
```

After what the above-mentioned error will never show up again. Here as an example:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install -U PyQtWebEngine
Requirement already satisfied: PyQtWebEngine in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (5.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQtWebEngine-Qt5>=5.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (12.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5>=5.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.7)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from PyQt5>=5.15.4->PyQtWebEngine) (5.15.2)
```

Repeat the same procedure for all offending packages.

Finally update spyder:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --force-reinstall spyder
```

And voila. A working spyder should be available.

As an aside: please note the `-H` option after `sudo`. This install packages under `/usr/local/lib/python3.xx/dist-packages` which will normally not conflict with `apt` system wide installed packages (which are under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`) and which you definitely don't want to touch another what than with `apt` actually!
I'm using this to avoid installing the same packages on a user-basis by invoking `pip` without `sudo`, which will install them under `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` for every user on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68798645)? This is exactly why you shouldn't use `sudo pip install`. Library versions get borked, inconsistencies arise, and stuff doesn't work.

Use `sudo pip` (for the last time) to uninstall Spyder and PyQT5, then reinstall the relevant packages using `apt`. Finally, upgrade Spyder using `pip install --user` (***no `sudo`!***). Everything *should* work okay after that.

Comment: See update: I can actually not uninstall PyQt5 this way.

Comment: OK, try force-reinstalling the `apt` packages (`man apt` for the exact flags). You'll have to search for their exact names - I think Spyder is just called `spyder`, but PyQt5 is broken up into several packages, one of which is `python-qtpy`, just to be different. I'd start with that one and `python3-pyqt5`, then work up the dependency chain as needed. After you do that, try running `spyder` and see if it starts without errors. If it does, run `pip install --user -U spyder` (`-U` is for upgrade) and it *should* work as expected :)

Comment: It seems that when installed with pip using `--user` spyder is then not found in the terminal: `bash: /usr/local/bin/spyder: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did `pip` give you a message about a directory not being on your PATH when you installed spyder?

Comment: Does running `hash -r` and then `spyder` help?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything: same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8952#issuecomment-473379633) worked:

```
pip install pyqtwebengine
```